# I can't Figure Out Why My Profile Pictures Aren't Appearing on my Profile Card

Tags: php, html, css, github

Alright, so I'm currently using this [REPOSITORY](https://github.com/msaad1999/PHP-Login-System) to help build a login system. It's mostly going great except, for the sake of preventing NSFW images, I'm wanting to allow them to choose from a predetermined profile picture labeled 1.png and 2.png respectively for the time being. These pictures exist in ../assets/images/

With that said, for some reason, the photos are not loading at all and I'm instead met with an empty frame.

This is my modification for the profile card

```
<div class='card card-profile text-center box-shadow bg-white'>

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['auth'])) { ?>

    <img alt='' class='card-img-top card-user-cover' src='../assets/images/banner.png'>
    <div class='card-block'>
        <a href='../profile'>
            <img src='../assets/images/<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar']; ?>.png' class='card-img-profile'>
        </a>
        <a href="../profile-edit">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-alt fa-1x edit-profile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-female"></i> -->
        </a>
        <h4 class='card-title'>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
            <small class="text-muted">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>
            </small>
            <small class="text-muted mt-2">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['last_name']; ?>
            </small>
            <small class="text-muted mt-4">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['headline']; ?>
            </small>
        </h4>
    </div>
    
    <?php } else { ?>

    <img alt='' class='card-img-top card-user-cover' src='../assets/images/banner.png'>
    <div class='card-block'>
        <a href='https://github.com/msaad1999/PHP-Login-System'>
            <img src='../assets/images/logo_blackbg.png' class='card-img-profile'>
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

and here is my auth_functions.php file that I added the 'avatar' field to in order to make it come across sessions. How might I go about rectifying this?

```
<?php

function check_logged_in() {

    if (isset($_SESSION['auth'])){

        return true;
    }
    else {

        header("Location: ../login/");
        exit();
    }
}

function check_logged_in_butnot_verified(){

    if (isset($_SESSION['auth'])){

        if ($_SESSION['auth'] == 'loggedin') {
    
            return true;
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['auth'] == 'verified') {

            header("Location: ../home/");
            exit(); 
        }
    }
    else {

        header("Location: ../login/");
        exit();
    }
}

function check_logged_out() {

    if (!isset($_SESSION['auth'])){

        return true;
    }
    else {

        header("Location: ../home/");
        exit();
    }
}

function check_verified() {

    if (isset($_SESSION['auth'])) {

        if ($_SESSION['auth'] == 'verified') {

            return true;
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['auth'] == 'loggedin') {

            header("Location: ../verify/");
            exit(); 
        }
    }
    else {

        header("Location: ../login/");
        exit();
    }
}

function force_login($email) {
    require '../assets/setup/db.inc.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if ($row['verified_at'] != NULL) {
                $_SESSION['auth'] = 'verified';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['auth'] = 'loggedin';
            }

            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
            $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender'];
            $_SESSION['headline'] = $row['headline'];
            $_SESSION['bio'] = $row['bio'];
            $_SESSION['profile_image'] = $row['profile_image'];
            $_SESSION['banner_image'] = $row['banner_image'];
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = $row['user_level'];
            $_SESSION['verified_at'] = $row['verified_at'];
            $_SESSION['created_at'] = $row['created_at'];
            $_SESSION['updated_at'] = $row['updated_at'];
            $_SESSION['deleted_at'] = $row['deleted_at'];
            $_SESSION['last_login_at'] = $row['last_login_at'];
            $_SESSION['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];

            return true;
        }
    }
}


function check_remember_me() {

    

    require '../assets/setup/db.inc.php';
    
    if (empty($_SESSION['auth']) && !empty($_COOKIE['rememberme'])) {
        
        list($selector, $validator) = explode(':', $_COOKIE['rememberme']);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM auth_tokens WHERE auth_type='remember_me' AND selector=? AND expires_at >= NOW() LIMIT 1;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {

            // SQL ERROR
            return false;
        }
        else {
            
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $selector);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if (!($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))) {

                // COOKIE VALIDATION FAILURE
                return false;
            }
            else {

                $tokenBin = hex2bin($validator);
                $tokenCheck = password_verify($tokenBin, $row['token']);

                if ($tokenCheck === false) {

                    // COOKIE VALIDATION FAILURE
                    return false;
                }
                else if ($tokenCheck === true) {

                    $email = $row['user_email'];
                    force_login($email);
                    
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I modified the pre-existing auth file to add the avatar file, uploaded the files into the appropriate directory, and modified the layout to pull the image file. I worry that there might be some css file somewhere that I'm having trouble locating since the frame is circular and I don't see where that modification is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use relative paths like "../assets" in your HTML, because the place you're generating your HTML from is almost certainly different from where your PHP is running.

Instead in your config/bootstrap file create defined paths, using const or define statements.

Many of my apps will have something like this:

```
define('APP_PATH', realpath(__DIR__));
define('WEB_PATH', APP_PATH . '/public');
define('LIB_PATH', APP_PATH . '/src/lib');
define('LOG_PATH', APP_PATH . '/log');
define('VIEW_PATH', APP_PATH . '/src/View');
```

Then you can use those in your HTML, like `<?php print WEB_PATH ?>/assets/images/` etc. This is a very common technique.

That allows you to move your files around (if need be) and change only 1 file.

Keep it simple!

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it. The relative paths are set up correctly but even making the transition to Defined paths didn't fix my issue. If I remove the php snippet and replace it with the file name, it shows the image exactly how I'd like it to so that tells me that the path isn't broken with either direct or relative. The problem seems to be that when it's looking for the image with this snippet:

<?php echo $_SESSION['avatar']; ?>

it's failing to locate the file name so where I should have something like

../assets/images/boy.png

I'm instead getting:

assets/images/.png

Comment: Where is $_SESSION['avatar'] being set?